# Is there any C++ function to sort a Map?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to know that how can I sort an `ordered_map` in C++ on the basis of values. Is there any function to do it?

Comment: What is an `ordered_map`? That's not a standard type...

Comment: You might look into [Boost.Bimap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) though.

Comment: If you are referring to `std::map`, it is already ordered, based on `std::less`. If you want a different order, pass in a different `Compare` when you instantiate the template.

Comment: Extending @jxh 's comment: `std::map`, as well as `std::set`, is mandated by the standard to be implemented as a binary search tree (the implementation chosen usually is a red-black-tree), so being sorted is an immanent feature... On the other hand, if you speak of `std::unordered_map` (or `set`) and just forgot the `un-`, then bad luck, you cannot sort, that would break hashing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It wasn't clear the OP intended `std::unordered_map`. Even the accepted answer uses `std::map`.

Comment: Why the question is about unordered_map, but all the answers are about map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not really change the elements of a `std::map`. However, you can use `std::vector` to first copy the elements in the vector and then use `std::sort()`.
[Sort elements of `std::map`](https://www.techiedelight.com/sort-map-values-cpp/).

```
#include<iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::pair<std::string,int> pair;

int main()
{
    // input map
    std::map<std::string,int> map = {
        {"two", 2}, {"one", 1}, {"four", 4}, {"three", 3}
    };

    // create an empty vector of pairs
    std::vector<pair> vec;

    // copy key-value pairs from the map to the vector
    std::copy(map.begin(),
            map.end(),
            std::back_inserter<std::vector<pair>>(vec));

    // sort the vector by increasing order of its pair's second value
    // if second value are equal, order by the pair's first value
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
            [](const pair& l, const pair& r) {
                if (l.second != r.second)
                    return l.second < r.second;

                return l.first < r.first;
            });

    // print the vector
    for (auto const &pair: vec) {
        std::cout << '{' << pair.first << "," << pair.second << '}' << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A *map* is an [associative container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_containers). Unlike [sequential containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_(C%2B%2B)), where you have control over the location of the element, an *associative container* itself controls the order of the elements. Once the associative container is created, the ordering cannot be changed.

There is no `ordered_map` in standard C++. There is `std::map`, which is a tree (and therefore the elements already appear sorted based on the comparator) and `std::unordered_map`, which is a hash table (the elements are somewhat ordered based on the hash of the key).

Answer (score 1):

This answer covers the case that you are referring to values inside the map itself.

First off, the container you want is `std::map`. There is no `ordered_map` in the standard library, only `map` or `unordered_map`.

You can supply `map` with your own comparer so that it sorts it like you want. For example:

```
struct MyOrder
{
    constexpr bool operator()(MyType a, MyType b) const 
    {
        // return true, so that a < b accodring to your definition
    }
};
```

and use it like

```
std::map<MyType, MyOrder> myMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rearrange elements of (`ordered_`)`map`(/`set`).

You might copy values (and/or keys) into `std::vector` and `std::sort` that.

Comment: Or you could copy the keys to a vector and sort them according to their values if you need them...

Answer (score 0):

No. A `std::map` is designed to store elements formed by a combination of a key value and a mapped value, where the key values are used to sort and identify the elements.

To sort by values, you could simply create an *inverted map*:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
std::map<T2, T1> invert(const std::map<T1, T2> & m)
{
    std::map<T2, T1> ret;
    for (const auto& e : m)
        ret[e.second] = e.first;
    return ret;
}
```

There are many solutions to this problem, and you might prefer one over the other in function of your needs.